# Rails 5 complete course and module per user when clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

So I have three level of functionality here, courses, course modules and course exercises.

However, I want to implement functionality where I can enable the users to tick a module of a course when they complete it, I did have this working previously, however, this was marking the modules complete for all users which are not the desired result I want.

So I have tried the following, where I have set up two new tables, one for `courses_users` and `course_modules_users` so I can capture the course users and add a record capturing the user id, course id, module id etc so it's completely unique to that user (so it doesn't make it as complete for all users)

Here is the schema in relation to the courses, course modules and exercises:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_12_115008) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "course_exercises", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "video"
    t.integer "course_module_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["course_module_id"], name: "index_course_exercises_on_course_module_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_course_exercises_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "course_modules", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_course_modules_on_course_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_course_modules_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "course_modules_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "course_module_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.boolean "complete"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["course_module_id"], name: "index_course_modules_users_on_course_module_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_course_modules_users_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "courses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "summary"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "trailer"
    t.integer "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_courses_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "courses_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "course_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.boolean "complete"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["course_id"], name: "index_courses_users_on_course_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_courses_users_on_user_id"
  end
end
```

Here is what the new tables look like:

[image]
[image]

For the models, I have done the following:

course.rb

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  has_many :course_modules

  validates :title, :summary, :description, :trailer, :price, presence: true

  def complete?
  end
end
```

course_exercise.rb

```
class CourseExercise < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :course_module

  validates :title, :description, :video, :course_module_id, presence: true
end
```

course_module.rb

```
class CourseModule < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  belongs_to :course
  has_many :course_exercises

  validates :title, :course_id, presence: true

  scope :completed, -> { where(complete: true) }
  after_save :update_course, if: :complete?

  def complete?
  end

  private

  def update_course
    course.complete! if course.course_modules.all?(&:complete?)
  end
end
```

course_modules_user.rb

```
class CourseModulesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_module
  belongs_to :user
end
```

courses_user.rb

```
class CoursesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user
end
```

For the controllers I have done the following:

courses/show.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <section class="pt-4 px-8">
    <section class="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
      <h3 class="font-normal text-grey-dark mb-4 py-2">
        <% if current_user.isAdmin? %>
          <%= @course.title %>
        <% else %>
          <%= @course.title %> Modules
        <% end %>
      </h3>
      <%= render 'layouts/dashboard/account' %>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="px-8">
    <% if Order.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, course_id: @course.id) %>
      <% @course_modules.each do |course_module| %>
        <section class="accordion-toggle">
          <section class="w-full sm:pr-4 pb-4">
            <section class="rounded shadow bg-grey-lighter border-b">
              <section class="flex justify-between px-6 p-4">
                <section class="flex items-center px-6 text-grey-darker">
                  <section class="font-bold text-base">
                    <%= course_module.title %>
                  </section>
                </section>

                <section class="flex items-center">
                  <% if user_signed_in? %>
                    <% if current_user.isAdmin? %>
                      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_module_path(course_module), class: "text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                    <% else %>
                      <% if course_module.complete? %>
                        <i class="fas fa-check text-green float-left mr-1"></i>
                        <span class="text-xs mr-2">Completed</span>
                      <% else %>
                        <%= link_to complete_course_module_path(course_module), method: :put do %>
                          <i class="fas fa-check text-grey-darkest float-left mr-2"></i>
                        <% end %>
                      <% end %>
                      <i class="flex items-center fal fa-angle-up"></i>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>

            <section class="accordion-items hidden">
              <% course_module.course_exercises.each do |exercise| %>
                <section class="w-full">
                  <section class="rounded shadow bg-grey-lighter border-b">
                    <section class="flex justify-between px-6 p-4">
                      <section class="flex items-center px-6 text-grey-darker">
                        <section class="font-bold text-base pl-4">
                          - <%= exercise.title %>
                        </section>
                      </section>

                      <section>
                        <% if user_signed_in? %>
                          <% if current_user.isAdmin? %>
                            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_course_exercise_path(exercise), class: "text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                          <% else %>
                            <%= link_to "View Exercise", exercise, class: "text-base text-grey-dark hover:text-darker px-4 py-2 border-2 border-grey leading-none no-underline hover:border-2 hover:border-grey-dark" %>
                          <% end %>
                        <% end %>
                      </section>
                    </section>
                  </section>
                </section>
              <% end %>
            </section>
          </section>
        </section>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <h3>You have not bought this course!</h3>

      <%= form_with(url: '/payments/create') do |f| %>
        <%= render partial: "stripe_checkout_button" %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:course_id, @course.id) %>

        <%= f.submit "Buy this course", class: "bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white font-semibold py-3 px-4 border-2 rounded-sm border-blue-dark shadow outline-none" %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </section>
<% else %>
  <section class="flex h-64 hero-banner p-4">
    <section class="flex items-center mx-auto">
      <h2 class="uppercase">
        <%= @course.title %>
      </h2>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="pt-4 px-4">
    <section class="w-full">
      <section class="rounded overflow-hidden shadow">
        <section style="padding: 56.25% 0 0 0; position: relative;">
          <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/<%= @course.trailer %>" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>

    <section class="flex flex-wrap -mx-4">
      <section class="w-full lg:w-3/4 p-4">
        <section class="bg-grey-lightest shadow text-grey-darker p-4">
          <h2 class="font-normal mb-4">Course description</h2>
          <p class="font-normal whitespace-pre-wrap"><%= @course.description %></p>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section class="w-full lg:w-1/4 p-4">
        <section class="bg-grey-lightest shadow text-grey-darker p-4 mb-4">
          <h3 class="font-normal mb-4">Course Price</h3>
          <p class="font-bold text-3xl text-green">£<%= @course.price %></p>
        </section>

        <%= link_to "Sign up to purchase", new_user_registration_path, class: "bg-blue hover:bg-blue-dark text-white font-semibold py-3 px-4 border-2 rounded-sm border-blue-dark shadow outline-none no-underline" %>

        <section class="bg-grey-lightest shadow text-grey-darker py-4 px-4 mt-4">
          <h3 class="font-normal mb-4">Course Modules</h3>
            <% @course_modules.each do |course_module| %>
              <section class="py-2 border-b-2 border-light modules">
                <%= course_module.title %>
              </section>
          <% end %>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
<% end %>
```

See how if I have if the module is complete, a green tick is supposed to be shown, and should ideally the record should go into the `course_modules_users` table because the completed field should mark the course module as `true` in the completed field.

**Some of the code in the models is from the previous solution that marked the course module for all users.**

**So if I'm right in thinking I should just need to move the current functionality into the new `complete?` methods and have the data capture in the new database tables**

However, this is a new thing for me to any help in knowing how to do this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right track

once a user buys a course or starts a course, you create all the required records in `course_users` and `course_modules_users` with `complete` set to `false`

add `courses_user_id` to `course_modules_users` table and you can remove `user_id`

`User` class

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :courses_users
  has_many :course_modules_users, through: :courses_users
end
```

`CoursesUser` class

```
class CoursesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :course_modules_users

  def completed!
    self.update_attributes(complete: true)
  end
end
```

`CourseModulesUser` class

```
class CourseModulesUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course_module
  belongs_to :courses_user

  after_update :update_courses_user, if: :completed?

  def siblings
    self.class.where(courses_user_id: self.courses_user_id)
  end

  def completed!
    self.update_attributes(complete: true)
  end

  def completed?
    siblings.all?(&:complete?)
  end

  def update_courses_user
    self.courses_user.completed!
  end
end
```

in `complete_course_module_path` controller action you can pull the `course_modules_users` records and mark it as complete

```
cmu = current_user.course_modules_users.find_by(course_module_id: params[:id])
      # params[:id] is course_modules.id
cmu.completed!
```

to show a course_module as completed in the view you can query `current_user.course_modules_users.find_by(course_module_id: params[:id])` and check `complete` column

A better way would be to use `CoursesUser` instead of `CourseModule` and pull the records from there
something like `current_user.courses_users.includes(course_modules_users: [course_module: :course_exercises]).find_by(course_id: 1)`

then you can move the `complete` functionality to a separate controller `CourseModulesUserController`